# Oracle function return table

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-functions

I don't know what is best solution for my problem. I need function with one parameter which resault is

```
VAL
-----
1
2
3
```

In function I need put union all to get all value.

```
Select column_1 as VAL from my_table where id = P_FUNCTION_PARAMETER --return 1
union all
Select column_2 as VAL from my_table where id = P_FUNCTION_PARAMETER --return 2
union all
Select column_3 as VAL from my_table where id = P_FUNCTION_PARAMETER; --return 3
```

What is the best solution for this?

Comment: So `column_1`, `column_2`, `column_3` are all of `number` data type? And, why do you need to do this with a function? Getting a table like that is a trivial task in plain SQL.

Comment: @mathguy  When call sql query in my aplication query editor get error: Value too long by XXX characters!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Best" just depends. Return a ref cursor or a collection, whichever you prefer.

For example:

```
SQL> create or replace function f_test_rc
  2    return sys_refcursor
  3  is
  4    rc sys_refcursor;
  5  begin
  6    open rc for
  7      select 1 from dual union all
  8      select 2 from dual union all
  9      select 3 from dual;
 10
 11    return rc;
 12  end;
 13  /

Function created.

SQL> select f_test_rc from dual;

F_TEST_RC
--------------------
CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

         1
----------
         1
         2
         3
```

---

```
SQL> create or replace function f_test_coll
  2    return  sys.odcinumberlist
  3  as
  4    l_coll  sys.odcinumberlist;
  5  begin
  6    select * bulk collect into l_coll
  7    from (select 1 from dual union all
  8          select 2 from dual union all
  9          select 3 from dual
 10         );
 11
 12    return l_coll;
 13  end;
 14  /

Function created.

SQL> select * from table(f_test_coll);

COLUMN_VALUE
------------
           1
           2
           3

SQL>
```

Comment: Did you notice the second part of the OP's question? He doesn't need hard-coded numbers in the output, he needs values picked up from a table.

Comment: @Littlefoot  Tnx for help,  your first example return resault in my example like this.  https://postimg.cc/F7NFYtSt   , second example I don't have sys.odcinumberlist

Answer (score 2):

First let's set up a small table for testing:

```
create table my_table
( id       number primary key
, column_1 number
, column_2 number
, column_3 number
);

insert into my_table
  select 1008, 3,   -8,  0.2  from dual union all
  select 1002, 6, null, -1.2 from dual
;
commit;
```

The function can look like this. Note that I don't use `union all` - that will require reading the table three times, when only one time is enough.

```
create or replace function my_function (p_function_parameter number)
  return sys.odcinumberlist
as
  arr sys.odcinumberlist;
begin
  select case ord when 1 then column_1
                  when 2 then column_2
                  when 3 then column_3 end
  bulk   collect into arr
  from   my_table cross join
         (select level as ord from dual connect by level <= 3)
  where  id = p_function_parameter
  order  by ord
  ;
  
  return arr;
end;
/
```

The function could be used, for example, like this: (in older versions you may need to wrap the function call within the `table` operator)

```
select * from my_function(1002);

COLUMN_VALUE
------------
           6

        -1.2
```

Comment: Tnx for answer, is it possible that I don't have sys.odcinumberlist  ?

Comment: @user_odoo - that would be extremely odd; it's a varray data type provided by Oracle itself, it is not something you create. I used it exactly so that I don't need to define a separate data type.

Comment: @user_odoo In any case: you can `create or replace type my_numberlist as varray(100) of number` and then use that instead of `sys.odcinumberlist` in the function. But if somehow `sys.odcinumberlist` is not available on your system, ask your DBA as that shouldn't happen unless someone somewhere did something wrong.